# How to use GetProcessImageFileName?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-2007

I'm trying to use [GetProcessImageFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/ms683217(v=vs.85).aspx) but I'm getting the following error:

> Undeclared identifier: 'GetProcessImageFileName'

I've tried adding `PsAPI` and `TlHelp32` to the uses clause but it has not solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this function is supplied by the RTL anywhere, but you can always just import it :

```
function GetProcessImageFileName(hProcess: THandle; 
                                 lpImageFileName: LPTSTR;
                                 nSize: DWORD): DWORD; stdcall;
                                 external 'PSAPI.dll' 
                                 name 'GetProcessImageFileNameA';
```

The ANSI version (for Delphi 2007) is imported above.  Alternatively, if supporting higher versions of delphi (with unicode strings) you would conditionally import `GetProcessImageFileNameW`.

Comment: The docs say that the DLL which implements the function is: *Kernel32.dll on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2;
Psapi.dll (if PSAPI_VERSION=1) on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2;
Psapi.dll on Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2003, and Windows XP*. Do you understand what that means?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That the above will not work on Windows 7?

Comment: I take it to mean that we are limited to `PSAPI_VERSION` of `1` on Win7, but it's a bit opaque to me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think this only matters if compiling using the C headers.  It sounds like `Psapi.dll` is a wrapper for `K32GetProcessImageFileName` on Win7+.  `Programs that must run on earlier versions of Windows as well as Windows 7 and later versions should always call this function as GetProcessImageFileName.`  I gather that the issue is just one of name resolution when using the header files, not the actual version of the function that will eventually be called (which should be the appropriate one for the platform).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  Remy seems to have discussed this here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/29369597/327083

Comment: Thanks for looking into that